# Postgresql 11 - pg_stat_statements - empty query column for some of queries

Tags: postgresql

we installed pg_stat_statements couple of days ago. Unfortunately, some of the queries does not show up in the view, e.g. the row is there but the 'query' column is empty. My guest is that the queries are too long and for some reason are too big to fit.

Comment: Maybe you exceeded [pg_stat_statements.max](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.38.8)

Comment: select count(distinct queryid) from pg_stat_statements shows around 9000 and show pg_stat_statements.max shows 10000. I guess it is not it?

Comment: Update: we restarted collecting statistics and so far no empty queries. So it might be pg_stat_statements.max value. Thanks! We will try different values and see the impact.

Comment: `pg_stat_statements.max` should cause it to discard whole rows, not just blank out the `query` column. I'm pretty sure I've seen some admin tools (pgAdmin3?) display empty cells when the values get too long. If it happens again, try running the query from `psql`.

Comment: @NickBarnes it would makes sense, doesn't it. But after the reset of pg_stat_statements queries started to show up and some of them weren't very long.